# Gnu Plot Horizontal Bar Graph with titles

Tags: gnuplot, gnu

I'm looking to create a bar graph using gnuplot that looks very similar to the following.
I have the raw data for the "Technology": "-0.72%" and so on in array.

I have gotten it up to horizontally drawing the graphs, but adjusting and making sure that the final image looks like seems to be beyond me. Any pointers are appreciated ?

[image]

Comment: Please show your data and your code.

Comment: Is your problem solved?  Any kind of feedback would be polite and appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sugggestion using the plotting style `boxxyerror` (check `help boxxyerror`).
The color is chosen depending on the column 2 values using the ternary operator (check `help ternary`).
The values are plotted as numbers using plotting style `with labels` and the alignment of the numbers which is either `right` for negative numbers and `left` for positive numbers is "filtered" using the ternary operator.

**Edit:**  Code changed such that it will show `+`-sign for positive numbers (and zero), and furthermore it will not matter whether your have the `%`-sign in your data or not (it will add `%` when plotting the label).

**Code:**

```
### Horizontal bar graph
reset session

$Data <<EOD
A  -3.5%
B  -1.3%
C   0.0%
D   1.5%
E   2.4%
F   5.3%
G   7.3%
EOD


myColor(col) = column(col)<0 ? 0xff0000 : column(col)==0 ? 0xcccccc : 0x00ff00
BoxWidth = 0.8
BoxYLow(i)  = i - BoxWidth/2.
BoxYHigh(i) = i + BoxWidth/2.

set style fill transparent solid 0.3
set yrange [:] reverse
unset key 
set offsets 1,1,0.5,0.5

plot $Data u (0):0:(0):2:(BoxYLow($0)):(BoxYHigh($0)):(myColor(2)):ytic(1) w boxxy lc rgb var, \
     '' u ($2<0?$2:NaN) :0:(sprintf("%+g%",$2)) w labels offset -0.5,0 right, \
     '' u ($2>=0?$2:NaN):0:(sprintf("%+g%",$2)) w labels offset  0.5,0 left
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]